# jQuery get width of ajax loaded elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a css `class` to ajax loaded html element. My HTML look like as below:

```
<h4 class="overflow-text"><span>This is the response from the ajax call.</span></h4>
```

This `h4` is a fixed width element and `span` inside `h4` may be overflowing. So I need to add a `CSS` class for `h4` if `span` text is overflowing. Here I am trying this with getting `width` of these two element and comparing it as below.

```
var el = $('h4.overflow-text');
el.each(function() {
  var span = $(this).find('span')
  if (span.width() > $(this).width()) {
    $(this).addClass('text-marquee')
    console.log('overflow')
  } else {
    console.log('not overflow')
  }
})
```

This works for me, if html not load from ajax. But not working on ajax responce. So I tried it on ajax sussess as below. But it also doesn't work for me.

```
success: function(res) {
  var $response = $("<div/>").html(res);
  var wp = $response.find('.overflow-text').width();
  var wc = $response.find('.overflow-text').children('span').width();


  console.log(wp,wc)

  $container.fadeOut( 50 , function() {
    jQuery(this).html( res);
  }).fadeIn( 1000 );
},
```

Doesn't works mean, wp and wc always giving 0.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: well it is not part of the DOM so it is not going to have widths

Comment: @epascarello what would be the work around for this to get width?

Comment: Are you populating the `span` before trying to get its width?

Comment: @PrakharSingh Upaded question with all contents of my ajax success

Comment: Please try to get the width after `jQuery(this).html( res);`

Comment: @PrakharSingh, just tried, it also gives 0

Comment: @user3733831 Please check my answer, Try to get the width using `jQuery(this).find('.overflow-text').width();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234596/discussion-between-prakhar-singh-and-user3733831).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the width of the element after the content has been added to the DOM should  work.

Edit: I saw that the DOM is not updated immediately however waiting for even a millisecond is enough and it gives the desired result.

```
    $.get("spantext", function(data, status){

          $('.container').fadeOut( 50 , function() {

            jQuery(this).html(data);

            $container = jQuery(this);
            setTimeout(function(){
                var wp = $container.find('.overflow-text').width();
                var wc = $container.find('.overflow-text').children('span').width();
                console.log(wp,wc)
            },1);

          }).fadeIn( 1000 );
    });
```

Comment: In this particular case you can wait a little longer (just to be safe) because the animation would hide the delay.